# Selecting a column from datatable to check its values

Tags: c#, datatable, datacolumn

I have a datatable which has 3 columns "Name","Type","ID" i want to use only one column in it for comparison. Which is "Type". I wanted to take that column put it in a DataColumn separated from the datatable, compare the values of the cells in it with a string and then pass a string if it matches.
I am not sure if this method is right or wrong, i even dont know how to get the string value of the cells (rows) in this Datacolumn to be compared

Here is my code for it :

```
DataTable Griddetails;
Griddetails = RxMUaClient.BrowseGrid("2", "127.0.0.1:48030", nodepassed);

var myColumn = Griddetails.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
                          .SingleOrDefault(col => col.ColumnName == "Type");

return Json(myColumn);
if (myColumn != null)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= myColumn.; i++ )
    {

    }
}
```

I am trying to get the datarow count in the dataColumn either by a for loop or foreach, the foreach is not working for some error and the i don't know how to get the value of the datacolumn for the for loop.

Any help ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. `myColumn` is a single `DataColumn`. A columns belongs to a table. A table can have multiple `DataRows` and every row has values for every column. But in total the number of rows for one column is the same as the number of rows in the table.

Comment: yes my question was i want to know the number of rows in this column to be able to check this in a comparison function

Comment: Every column has the same number of rows as the table itself, so `myColumn.Table.Rows.Count`. Your question is still pointless, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks, i will check it.

Comment: Why do i keep getting negative reviews !! and somebody added an answer and was it then he edited my question and removed the answer !!

Comment: You got downvotes because you haven't clarified the question. _"get the datarow count in the dataColumn"_ seems pointless since a columns cannot have rows but the table.  So people were confused what you actually want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the question still doesn't make much sense to me, if you just want to know how many rows a table has that belongs to a given `DataColumn`:

```
int rowCount = myColumn.Table.Rows.Count;
```

Note that you don't need the LINQ query to find the column, you can use the `DataColumnCollection` [indexer that takes a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fyswbf(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
DataColumn myColumn = Griddetails.Columns["Type"];
```

It works as desired if there is no column with that name and returns `null`.

---

After your edited question it seems that you actually want to find row(s) which type-column contain a given value. You can use LINQ:

```
var matchingRows = from row in Griddetails.AsEnumerable()
                   where row.Field<string>("Type") == valueYouSearch
                   select row;

DataRow firstRow = matchingRows.FirstOrDefaul();
if(firstRow != null)
{
    // here you know that there is at least one row with that value in the type-column
    string firstType = firstRow.Field<string>("Type"); // pointless, maybe you want to return different column's value
    // ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks please check my question again, hopefully it is clearer

Comment: @KamalF: now your requirement seems to be different. You want to find a value in a string column. What value? What do you want to do with matching rows? Just check if the value exists or return matching rows?

Comment: just check if the value exists and if so, it returns the value, if not it returns empty string variable

Comment: @KamalF: i would return `null` if the value doesn't exist. Otherwise you can't differentiate between a found empty string or a not found empty string(if you search that value). However, why do you want to return a value that you are searching instead of just a `bool` that indicates whether the table contained it or not? What is the value/variable that you're searching?

Comment: Or do you want to return the row-count of the matching rows? Then i understand your original question.

Comment: Actually i wanted to return both a bool and the value at the beginning but it seemed to be difficult and i though about only a value and if it is not then it would be considered as false bool. 
The idea is that i am searching for a type of data in that table for presence. If it is present it should be represented in a label in a view of the MVC application. So after this comparison the return will be passed to the View by Json and presented for the user. Is it clear now ?